# ACPI wakeup from keyboard/mouse via /proc/acpi/wakeup after suspend. How to find the correct device?

Tags: linux, suspend, acpi

I'd like to wakeup my system via keyboard or mouse. This can be done via */proc/acpi/wakeup* and a simple

```
echo DEVNAME > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

my wakeup file looks like this

```
       Device   S-state   Status   Sysfs node
  ---------------------------------------
  1. P0P2     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:01.0
  2. P0P3     S4    *disabled  
  3. P0P1     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0
  4. UAR1     S4    *disabled  pnp:00:0c
  5. EUSB     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.7
  6. USBE     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.7
  7. P0P5     S4    *disabled  
  8. P0P6     S4    *disabled  
  9. P0P7     S4    *disabled  
  10. P0P8    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
  11. P0P9    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.5
  12. GBEC    S4    *disabled  
  13. USB0    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
  14. USB1    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.1
  15. USB2    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.2
  16. USB3    S4    *disabled  
  17. USB4    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
  18. USB5    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.1
  19. USB6    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.2
  20. P0P4    S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
```

My question is: **How can I find out which (USB) device belongs to my mouse/keyboard?** I failed with *lsusb* so far, but maybe I just missed the right switches.

Comment: You can't go too far wrong by just enabling all of your usb ports.  Or you can enable one at a time until you find the one that makes it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've found a way, though it does not look very clean ;)

I'll start from the end - running this one-liner will tell you the truth:

```
grep "USB.*pci" /proc/acpi/wakeup |\
    cut -d ':' -f 2- |\
    while read aaa; do \
        find /dev/.udev \
            -name "*$aaa*" \
            -print \
            -exec grep "$aaa" /proc/acpi/wakeup \; -exec echo \; ;\
    done
```

Nice, isn't it? And here is, how it works:

- The beginning should be obvious: `grep "USB.*" /proc/acpi/wakeup` extracts from the list only USB devices that have a known sysfs node.
- `cut -d ':' -f 2-` leaves just the ending (numbers) after 'pci:' on each line.
- Then, for each ending (`aaa=0000:00:1d.2` and so on), try to find an **udev device symlink** that contains the string.
- For each device symlink found, the find command :

  - prints the name of udev symlink, **<-- this is the most useful part**
  - executes grep to display the line from `/proc/acpi/wakeup` that corresponds to the found device,
  - appends a blank line for output clarity.

So, thanks to the meaningful naming of device symlinks by udev, you can tell which USB device is the keyboard, mouse etc.

Comment: This method seems to return nothing in my case

Answer (score 7):

```
grep `ls /dev/input/by-path/*-mouse |\
    head -1 |\
    cut -d- -f 3` /proc/acpi/wakeup |\
    gawk '{print $1}'
```

This finds the input device for your mouse, then looks up the PCI ID in /proc/acpi/wakeup to give you the name.  In fact, you could just redirect the output of that command back to /proc/acpi/wakeup in order to enable wakeups from that device.